# Implementing PROMISE on a product detail page for ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I read few articles about angular promise but I still dont feel that much comfortable about its implementation in my current requirement but have become inevitable in one of my pages.

**Issue**: My **Qty** dropdown is showing blank and I am sure it can be handles using `promise`.

```
 <div ng-show="product[0].sizeQtyPrice">
    <div>Qty
       <select ng-model="product.selectedQty" ng-options="value for value in product.selectedQtyOptions" ng-change="onQtyChanged(product[0].id, product[0].selectedQty)"></select>
     </div>
 </div>
```

My Controller:

```
var ProductDetailController = function($scope,$http){

    $http.get("/get_product_details/?prod_id=1")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.product = response;
            $scope.onSizeSelected($scope.product[0].id, $scope.product[0].sizeQtyPrice[0]);
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Error happened ... ');
        });


    //original code starts here
    $scope.getItemQtyPrice = function(sizeQtyPrice, qty) {
      var pricePerItem = sizeQtyPrice.mrp * ( 1 - sizeQtyPrice.discountPercent / 100);
      var totalItemPrice = qty * pricePerItem
      console.log('Total price for ' + qty + ' qty is ' + totalItemPrice);
      return totalItemPrice;
    };

    $scope.onSizeSelected = function(productId, sizeQtyPrice){
      console.log('size selected ...' + sizeQtyPrice);
      $scope.updateSelectedProductBySizeSelected(productId ,sizeQtyPrice);
    };


    $scope.onQtyChanged = function(productId, qty){
      $scope.updateSelectedProductByQtySelected(productId, qty);
    };

    $scope.updateSelectedProductBySizeSelected = function(productId, sizeQtyPrice)
    {
    var item = _.findWhere($scope.product, { 'id': productId } )
    if (item != undefined)
    {
      item.selectedQtyOptions = _.range(1, sizeQtyPrice.qty + 1);
      item.selectedSize = sizeQtyPrice.size;
      item.selectedQty = item.selectedQtyOptions[0];

      var sizeQtyPrice = _.findWhere(item.sizeQtyPrice , {"size" : item.selectedSize});
      item.totalPriceForSelectedQtyAndSize = $scope.getItemQtyPrice(sizeQtyPrice, item.selectedQty);
      item.totalWithoutDiscount = sizeQtyPrice.mrp * item.selectedQty;
      item.pricePerPiece = item.totalPriceForSelectedQtyAndSize / item.selectedQty;
    }
    };

    $scope.updateSelectedProductByQtySelected = function(productId, qty){
    var item = _.findWhere($scope.product, { 'id': productId } )

    if (item != undefined)
    {
      item.selectedQty = qty;

      var sizeQtyPrice = _.findWhere(item.sizeQtyPrice , {"size" : item.selectedSize});
      item.totalPriceForSelectedQtyAndSize = $scope.getItemQtyPrice(sizeQtyPrice, item.selectedQty);
      item.totalWithoutDiscount = sizeQtyPrice.mrp * item.selectedQty;
      item.pricePerPiece = item.totalPriceForSelectedQtyAndSize / item.selectedQty;
    }
    };

};

mainApp.controller('ProductDetailController',['$scope','$http',ProductDetailController]);
```

Below is the `product` JSON:

```
[
{
"selectedQtyOptions": [],
"selectedSize": "",
"description": "taxiing",
"selectedQty": "1",
"title": "nationally",
"brand": "Brand2",
"product_identifier_type": "SKU",
"images": [
    {
        "image0": "/media/products/bb61e8ae422b736ff6c1b9562cbde883.jpg"
    }
],
"sizeQtyPrice": [
    {
        "discountAttributes": "Jung fords redskin richest pearl paperweight careen confides backstage gushing",
        "measureUnit": "mm",
        "discountPercent": 5,
        "mrp": 8269,
        "qty": 2,
        "size": 62
    },
    {
        "discountAttributes": "snitched wisps unambiguously harshest clothed famished spec triathlon Ethelred addicts",
        "measureUnit": "Kg",
        "discountPercent": 10,
        "mrp": 5644,
        "qty": 6,
        "size": 92
    },
    {
        "discountAttributes": "committal forming Welsh mawkishly swapped merchandize brawn demises emailed UCLA",
        "measureUnit": "Kg",
        "discountPercent": 3,
        "mrp": 7106,
        "qty": 5,
        "size": 32
    }
],
"product_identifier": "8e4e9389-6c46-4dc8-8716-0c7d2e580d3e",
"id": 1
}
]
```

Comment: Why don't you provide a jsfiddle with the code? It always makes it easier to help.

Comment: Probably because it's an empty array `"selectedQtyOptions": [],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting selectedQtyOptions on product[0] but you are trying to read it from product. I did not test it but I believe this should work.

```
 <select ng-model="product.selectedQty" ng-options="value for value in product[0].selectedQtyOptions" ng-change="onQtyChanged(product[0].id, product[0].selectedQty)"></select>
```

Or

```
$scope.updateSelectedProductBySizeSelected = function(productId, sizeQtyPrice)
....
if (item != undefined)
{
  $scope.selectedQtyOptions = _.range(1, sizeQtyPrice.qty + 1);
  $scope.selectedSize = sizeQtyPrice.size;
  $scope.selectedQty = item.selectedQtyOptions[0];
}
...
```

FYI you are already using a promise. http().success is a promise, so you are only updating it after you get the data. Another thing, I find your approach a bit confusing and I honestly did not understand what you are trying to do. Just a few advices:

- Do not pass ids and then look for the entry in the JSON data. It's a waste of time. If you can pass the object directly.
- Separate the ng-model variables from the GET response. It makes it quite confusing.